# question about using AutoLayout in an application with many animations - past failure; has anything changed

Tags: ios, autolayout

We have a utility app that has like 10 major animations for manipulating the UI. A new developer suggested that we convert from managing position in code to using AutoLayout. We have tried this once before and it just really didn't work (and all constraints in code) and the constraints would break.  Are we being Luddites by not adopting AutoLayout or are major projects not using it?

Has anything significant changed where this would be easier from 18 months ago? My feeling is that if we don't absolutely need it, we're better off staying just manipulating frames in code.

Answer (score 0):

Using autolayout is necessary because the screen sizes vary so much.  Trying to modify layout constraints manually to mimic what you currently have can be a HUGE head ache.

A solution is to move the animation code into storyboards (well as much as possible anyway).  The code you have to maintain will most likely shrink dramatically from pre-autolayout to using autolayout (depending on the animation type).  [Here's a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KVKXlh6sKI)